# The association of rails automatically save data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have these models with their relations and `user_id` column in  `request` table, does request `table` save automatically `user_id`?

`class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :users
 end`

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :requests
 end`

Comment: No Associations just relate the models.The data is saved by creating records.

Comment: Only if you do (e.g) request.user = current_user. Once you've set user on request, the id of the user will be saved in requests, given you've got the migrations right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You will need to make a user_id column on the requests table, in order to save that association.

Also, I think you may want to use

```
belongs_to :user
```

instead of

```
has_one :users
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-models.htm) you could check out that will help explain associations.

Answer (score 0):

To add user_id column to Request you have to run a migration:

```
rails g migration AddUserIdToRequest
```

Then search for the file and inside `def change` do this:

```
def change
  add_column :requests, :user_id, :integer
end
```

And finally, you have to run the migration by doing this:

```
rake db:migrate
```